# How to use iter function to loop through a list until a certain match is found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I frankly don't understand how to use the [`iter(o[,sentinel])`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function and I'm trying to loop through `lst`*(a list)* and print all the values until `'kdawg'`

Code:

```
lst = [2,3,4,'kdawg',5,6,'hey']

class foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(lst)

for i in iter(foo,'kdawg'):
    print i
```

I expect it to return:

```
2
3
4
```

However it returns the whole list **continuously:**

```
[2,3,4,'kdawg',5,6,'hey']
```

Why doesn't my `iter()` function work?

Comment: Do you have a question? It is difficult to know precisely what you want, or find precisely where you knowledge gap exists, unless you ask a specific question.

Comment: @Robᵩ Why doesn't my iter() function work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `functools.partial` if you want to do this using `iter`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
for i in iter(partial(next, iter(lst)), 'kdawg'):
        print i
...     
2
3
4
```

`iter` expects you pass a callable that returns values one by one, which is your case is that class and call to that class returns a new instance each time, which is not equal to the sentinel value passed to `iter`.

```
>>> p = partial(next, iter(lst))
>>> p()
2
>>> p()
3
>>> p()
4
>>> p()
'kdawg'
```

While in your code, `i` is always an instance of that `class`:

```
for i in iter(foo,'kdawg'):
    print repr(i)
```

**output:**

```
<__main__.foo instance at 0xa15286c>
<__main__.foo instance at 0xa15284c>
<__main__.foo instance at 0xa15286c>
...
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`itertools.takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> 
>>> l = [2,3,4,'kdawg',5,6,'hey']
>>> 
>>> for i in takewhile(lambda s: s != 'kdawg', l):
...     print i
... 
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Slice the list from the start until `lst.index('kdawg')`

```
>>> lst = [2,3,4,'kdawg',5,6,'hey']
>>> for i in lst[:lst.index('kdawg')]:
...     print i 
2
3
4
```

Note: you many want to handled the `ValueError` if the item is not found in the list:

```
def iterUpto(a, ele):
    '''
    If ele is in a return sublist from 0 to index(ele) otherwise return a
    '''
    if ele in a: return a[:a.index(ele)]              
    return a
```

With `ele` in the list:

```
>>> a = [2,3,4,'kdawg',5,6,'hey']
>>> for i in iterUpto(a, 'kdawg'):
...     print i
2
3
4
```

With `ele` not in the list:

```
>>> for i in iterUpto(a, 'foo'):
...     print i
2
3
4
kdawg
5
6
hey
```

Answer (score 0):

A fourth option:

```
for i in lst:
    if i == 'kdawg':
        break
    print i
```

Or if you need to make a new list:

```
new_lst = []
for i in lst:
    if i == 'kdawg':
        break
    new.append(i)
```

Or instead of making a new list, a generator function!

```
def not_kdawg:
    for i in lst:
        if i == 'kdawg':
            break
        yield i
```